# Is it possible to show different UI according the user sign in Firebase(Admin UI/User UI)

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to show different UI according to the user sign-in. if the user signs in with the user email app will navigate to the user page. and if the admin signs in with the admin email app will navigate to the admin page. **How can I achieve this in Firebase**

> I don't want to validate in the frontend

Comment: For that you have to set roles in your user table and in start of application fetch loggedin user and check its role and set ui according to role.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the user is loggedIn or not

-> If logged in :

-> Fetch User data from Firestore then

```
Scaffold(body:(user.role == 'Admin')? AdminView(): UserView())
```